# Как разлогиниться из VK API в iOS приложении?

Tags: ios, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Я добавил кнопку `Войти через ВК`. И хочу добавить возможность разлогиниться и поменять аккаунт.

Пробовал запустить этот запрос `http://api.vk.com/oauth/logout`. Но он выводит `wrong logout hash`.

Использовал этот код:

```
let logoutUrl = "http://api.vk.com/oauth/logout"

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: logoutUrl)!,
cachePolicy:.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData,
timeoutInterval:60.0)
let responseData = try! NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: nil)
```

Также пробовал почистить NSDefaults, после logout:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.removeObjectForKey("VKAccessUserId")
defaults.removeObjectForKey("VKAccessToken")
defaults.removeObjectForKey("VKAccessTokenDate")
defaults.synchronize()
```

И почистить кукисы:

```
let storage = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage()
for cookie in storage.cookies ?? [] {
    let domainName = cookie.domain
    let domainRange = domainName.rangeOfString("vk.com")

    if let range = domainRange where range.count > 0 {
        storage.deleteCookie(cookie)
    }
}
```

Не помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я нашел решение. Нужно вызвать `VKSdk.forceLogout()`

Answer (score 0):

По поводу ошибки `wrong logout hash` проблема существует еще с прошлого года: http://www.flasher.ru/forum/showthread.php?t=210434

Пример функции logout:

```
- (IBAction)logout:(id)sender {
    // Запрос на logout
    NSString *logout = @"http://api.vk.com/oauth/logout";

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:logout] 
                                                            cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData 
                                                        timeoutInterval:60.0]; 
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    if(responseData){
        NSDictionary *dict = [[JSONDecoder decoder] parseJSONData:responseData];
        NSLog(@"Logout: %@", dict);

        // Приложение больше не авторизовано, можно удалить данные
        isAuth = NO;
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"VKAccessUserId"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"VKAccessToken"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"VKAccessTokenDate"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

        [self sendSuccessWithMessage:@"Выход произведен успешно!"]; 
    }
}
```

Несмотря на то, что ВКонтакте отвечает ошибкой, выход пользователя все-таки происходит :)

```
Logout: {
    error = "invalid_client";
    "error_description" = "client_id is incorrect";
}
```

Источник: https://habrahabr.ru/post/133504/

Comment: Я читал этот пост и по нему делал логаут. Не помогло и ошибка другая, не такая как в этом посте

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно:

For swift 3+

let dataStore = WKWebsiteDataStore.default()
dataStore.fetchDataRecords(ofTypes: WKWebsiteDataStore.allWebsiteDataTypes()) { (records) in
    for record in records {
        if record.displayName.contains("facebook") {
            dataStore.removeData(ofTypes: WKWebsiteDataStore.allWebsiteDataTypes(), for: [record], completionHandler: {
                print("Deleted: " + record.displayName);
            })
        }
    }
}